# Mamp 2.2 and intl.so for ICU

Tags: php, symfony, mamp, homebrew

I have Mamp 2.2 with php 5.5.3 and Mac osx 10.8.5

i don't find intl.so in my modules and on web,
and this is recommendations of symfony project

before i use this (https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php) 
but now i can't use php55

```
brew options php55
Error: No available formula for php55
```

i have already tried to install my old intl.so (php 5.4) 
but dosen't works

Answer (score 2):

Use `port`, look here: [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/)

Next:

```
port search php55-intl
```

Result:

```
php55-intl @5.5.4 (php, devel)
    internationalization extension for PHP
```

From `PHP 5.5.3` to `PHP 5.5.4` were no changes in `intl`, so it should work - [PHP 5.5.4 Changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.4)

And install it:

```
port install php55-intl
```

After install copy `intl.so` (from: `/opt/local/lib/php55/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/`, path in my system) library to extension dir of `MAMP` and load in `php.ini`.

Comment: if there are no problems before I installed homebrew?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the "Error: No available formula for php55" try:

```
brew tap --repair
```

To add the intl extension, you could reinstall php with

```
brew reinstall php --with-intl
```

but in the current version 5.5.5 is an issue, so you have to install intl with:

```
brew install php55-intl
```